# How to get Banners Ads from leadbolt in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, leadbolt

I am trying to integrate Leadbolt ads in my iphone app, i added a banner ad through leadbolt website to diplay on my iphone app and it displayed the following dialog:

[image]

It's confusing me how to use this link in my code to make a url request using uiwebview to integrate the banner ad, kindly help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SDK allows for more advanced ad units such as notifications, overlays, app icons and more. These ad units generally perform better and provide better returns overall. If you are only interested in HTML banners then you do not need to link the SDK.

However, this should help you:

```
NSString *pageHTML = @"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://ad.leadbolt.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=my_section_id\"></script>"];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:pageHTML baseURL:nil];
```

You can always contact me support at leadbolt.com quoting your ticket id (ROA-618293).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Can you provide me reference of some iphone app which has leadbolt ads in it ,and if possible, some sample code also??

Comment: You have mentioned in the documentation to use the SDK to get ads, if i have to use webview this way, then where is the use of SDK then?

Comment: @JamalZafar and LeadBolt Tech Support, How to get response whether Ad is available or not? And can I refresh ads for a certain time for example, 30 Seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Adding it here for future use:

In ios cocos2d app

```
 UIView* glView = [CCDirector sharedDirector].view;
 LeadboltOverlay *ad = [LeadboltOverlay createAdWithSectionid:@"PLACE_KEY_HERE" view:glView];

    // adjust the banner dynamically by 50 pixels from its designated position
[ad setAdditionalDockingMargin:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 50]];
[ad loadAd];
```

in normal ios app replace line with

```
LeadboltOverlay *ad = [LeadboltOverlay createAdWithSectionid:@"PLACE_KEY_HERE" view:self.view];
```

For Landscape mode add it before `[ad loadAd];`

```
[LeadboltOverlay setLandscapeMode:@"1"]
```

Comment: Can anybody tell how to turn it into Landscape mode...  I am getting portrait.

Comment: I am not able to close ads shown using leadbolt sdk